# How do I make a copy of a published Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

There's a Google Sheet with some info I need but I can't make a copy because published view removes the Spreadsheet UI. How do I make a copy?

Comment: Are you the owner of the sheet, or an editor?

Comment: I just have permission to view. I cannot edit nor am i the owner.

Comment: Sounds like the owner has made a deliberate decision that you should not be able to make a copy of the spreadsheet.